# How to solve SFC Verification problems?

Tags: windows, driver

Running test of "Reinstall with IO Before and After" on HCK Test Studio for Driver Certification , failed with information below:

--SFC verification

--Opening cbs.log failed! Will re-try after 30 seconds

--Failed

Answer (score 1):

Even I encountered the same issue. I resolved this by running "sfc.exe /scannow" command from cmd. This command detected some file corruptions on the system and then it fixed them. 
Then, when I re-ran the test, it passed.

Regds,
Kunal

Comment: fistly, thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried that but when i re-ran the test, it didn't pass. Also do it need an internet connection for "sfc.exe /scannow"?